# Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04 Very Slow

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

Can you please guide why Android Studio latest version is very slow to use on Ubuntu 14.04 with all latest upgrades, 4 Giga Memory and Core i5 system , otherwise Ubuntu and system are fast and I develop lot of stuff on this system like mostly in PHP, JS etc.

However as I started to do some Android app development, I am finding hard to use my system with Android Studio. I have even replaced OpenJDK with Oracle's JDK as was recommended by Google Android Studio, it improved and now system getting greyed and stuck is no more issue, but still using Studio for any action is very slow, and almost impossible to work without getting laggy windows and slow responses.

Any tips to make Android Studio work fine at Ubuntu 14.04 please?

Comment: @JaiminModi Thanks for sharing your experience. Should I switch to Eclipse then its performance is better on Ubuntu than Android Studio?

Comment: I am new to asking questions on SO, why downvotes? Can you please guide in comments?

Comment: it because in general questions like *tool X runs slow* not fit SO ...

Comment: @Selvin thanks for the insight. Can I migrate it to some relevant section of the site? Will avoid that in future. Thanks. Irony is I have answered many questions and like SO, but trying to ask a question for a problem I am facing myself is hard. Kudos to all people who get their questions answered here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**System working very slow** is the major issue while working with the Android Studio.
 Please follow the details given below :

The minimum and recommanded hardware requirements for Android Studio are:

Linux

```
GNOME or KDE desktop
GNU C Library (glibc) 2.11 or later
2 GB RAM minimum, 4 GB RAM recommended
400 MB hard disk space
At least 1 GB for Android SDK, emulator system images, and caches
1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution
Oracle® Java Development Kit (JDK) 7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have all the recommended hardware requirements. Still It is slow.

Comment: There must be some other reason responsible for this issue. Trying defragmenting your disk and cleaning recent history might helps you.  Here is the link to speed up ubuntu system : http://www.howtogeek.com/115797/6-ways-to-speed-up-ubuntu/

Comment: System in general is normal and works just fine. It was just this only program with sluggish performance. Seems like I have to look for some other tool instead of Android Studio. By the way one thing which really helped solve about 50% problem was switching from OpenJDK to Oracle JDK which I mentioned in my question. I thought there might by some other relevant thing which might help.